# SQL How to update a column with data from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID START_DATE     ADD_DAYS    NEW_DATE    
------------------------------------------
1  02/02/2017     5     
2  06/24/2017     3      
3  07/14/2017     9      
4  05/19/2017     12
```

I have the following table and I want to go in and update the column NEW_DATE with data that I read from the table itself. I am struggling to understand the correct MS SQL to achieve that. Any help?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: If you can control the schema, it might be worth adding this `new_date` column as a calculated column. (e.g. `alter table table_name add new_date as dateadd(day,add_days,start_date)`. That way you don't need to update anything and any changes to `add_days` or `start_date` are automatically recalculated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET NEW_DATE = DATEADD(day, ADD_DAYS, START_DATE)
```

If you need to update rows using conditions, you can do for example:

```
UPDATE MYTABLE SET NEW_DATE = DATEADD(day, ADD_DAYS, START_DATE)
WHERE ID < 10
```

Comment: Can I ad conditional statements to the SET NEW_DATE? I have a lot of different scenarios that I would like to accommodate.

Comment: @Teeko . . . Ask another question with more detail.  You have two very good answers to the question you actually asked.

Comment: @Teeko: see updated answer, for more complex conditions that do not depend on table values you'd need another alternative, ask another question if that's your case

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the schema, it might be worth adding this `NEW_DATE` column as a calculated column.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD NEW_DATE as DATEADD(DAY,ADD_DAYS,START_DATE)
```

That way you don't need to update anything and any changes to add_days or start_date are automatically recalculated

Comment: Thanks Icarus, that would be a great idea except I have conditional update statements and also will need to run this update on a scheduled basis.